# Specifying multiple PKG_PATH addresses in OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd

Can multiple PKG_PATH addresses be specified in OpenBSD?

I ask as, I am new to the BSD world, and the following document, https://stable.mtier.org, seems to imply so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PKG_PATH=URL1:URL2:URL3`. Anyway, you should use directly mtier's `openup` script, it will automate the process.

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, Rufo. I will indeed use openup.